# How is formatting retained on the clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, copy-paste, rich-text-editor, plaintext

When copy & pasting formatted text, where does the separation between content and formatting occur? For example, copy & pasting from Word. When the content is copied, it can be pasted into something like TinyMCE which can retain the formatting, or into a regular browser textarea which will strip the formatting.

I've been told that the stripping of the formatting occurs by the application that is having content pasted into it. Because of this, pasting formatted content is unreliable.

However, to me it seems like the clipboard either has two versions of the content, and pastes the appropriate one, or one version is copied but the formatting is somehow flagged so that an app can request the content with or without the formatting.

How and where does this separation occur?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question scoped to a specific operating system?

Comment: This functionality exists on both Mac and Windows. I'm not sure if they both handle it the same way or not. If they handle it differently, I'd like to know the answer for each.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about Word, I'm assuming you're asking about Windows:
[Clipboard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).